# Как создать полупрозрачный градиент?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

В главный контейнер `main_box` я добавляю кнопку `btn` и цветной контейнер `box`.

В `box` добавляю два виджета:

1. `back_picture` - изображение, которое располагается в верхней части контейнера, полученное с помощью класса `BackPicture`. Кнопка `btn`, привязанная к методу `remake` класса `MyWindow`, меняет картинку в `back_picture`.
2. Надпись `label`, которая указывает на то, что `back_picture` не является единственным виджетом контейнера `box`.

Окно приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас мне нужно наложить на `back_picture` градиент с особыми характеристиками:

1. Вертикальный
2. Крайняя нижняя точка имеет цвет #2A303D и **100% непрозрачности**
3. Крайняя верхняя точка имеет цвет #2A303D и **50% непрозрачности**
4. Очень важно! Центр градиента не расположен посередине, т.е. нижняя и верхняя точки неравноправны. Центр градиента смещен в сторону верхней точки, значит, нижняя занимает доминирующее положение. Обозначил точку центра градиента красной стрелкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нарисовал картинку, которая показывает разницу наглядно. Цифрой **1** обозначил градиент со смещенным центром(как мне надо), цифрой **2** обозначил градиент без смещенного центра(как мне **НЕ** надо):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Градиент с цифрой 1 является моей целью**

Покажу цветом, как градиент может быть смещен в сторону какой-либо точки, чтобы было понятнее. В первом случае градиент смещен в сторону нижней точки, во втором случае - в сторону верхней точки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работая в illustrator'е я заметил, что png запоминает уровень прозрачности пикселя. Это натолкнуло меня на мысль, что картинку градиента можно просто сохранить и расположить над `back_picture`.

Картинка градиента:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если открыть эту картинку в каком-нибудь графическом редакторе, полупрозрачные пиксели будут действительно полупрозрачными. Но, к моему большому разочарованию, в окне приложения градиент отображается сплошным квадратом цвета #2A303D:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно как-то создать градиент с **точно такими же** характеристиками и расположить его **ровно** над `back_picture`(важно, чтобы не было видно стыков), сохранив возможность менять изображение в `back_picture`. Пожалуйста, помогите мне сделать это

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class BackPicture(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BackPicture, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x
        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(self.x, self.x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.index = 1

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Remake', clicked = self.remake)

        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.container.setStyleSheet('background: #2A303D;')
        self.container.setMinimumHeight(300)
        self.container.setFixedWidth(300)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_box.addWidget(btn)        
        main_box.addWidget(self.container)

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.container)
        box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.back_picture = BackPicture('picture3.jpg', 300, self.container)
        self.back_picture.move(0, 0)

        #self.gradient = BackPicture('gradient.png', 300, self.container)
        #self.gradient.move(0, 0)   НЕ РАБОТАЕТ

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text number 1')
        label.setStyleSheet(qss)
        box.addStretch(6)
        box.addWidget(label, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        box.addStretch(1)

    def remake(self):
        if self.index == 1:
            self.back_picture.setPicture('picture2.png') 
            self.index = 2
        else:
            self.back_picture.setPicture('picture3.jpg') 
            self.index = 1


qss = '''QLabel {
             color: white;
             font: bold 16px;
             background: transparent;
         }'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/882546/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-css-%D0%B2-qt

Comment: Не могли бы вы мне рассказать или поделиться ссылкой, где описывают, что значит x1, x2, y1, y2? Я никак не могу понять, как задать правильно координаты

Comment: Мне кажется, я разобрался :) Пока не надо

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, я сделал градиент, как это делают по вашей ссылке. Но как сместить центр градиента, которому я уделил особое внимание в вопросе, там не говорят. Не знаете ли вы, как это сделать?

Comment: Меняете координаты области градиента, меняется его центр

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализовать примерно такой градиент можно следующим образом(значения в таблице стиля лучше выставлять по своему усмотрению):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class BackPicture(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BackPicture, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x
        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(self.x, self.x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.index = 1

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Remake', clicked = self.remake)

        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.container.setStyleSheet('background: #2A303D;')
        self.container.setMinimumHeight(300)
        self.container.setFixedWidth(300)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_box.addWidget(btn)        
        main_box.addWidget(self.container)

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.container)
        box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.back_picture = BackPicture('white.png', 300, self.container)
        self.back_picture.move(0, 0)

        gradient = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.container)
        gradient.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        gradient.setStyleSheet(gradient_qss)
        gradient.move(0, 0)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text')
        label.setStyleSheet(label_qss)
        box.addStretch(1)
        box.addWidget(label, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        box.addStretch(1)

    def remake(self):
        if self.index == 1:
            self.back_picture.setPicture('picture1.png') 
            self.index = 2
        else:
            self.back_picture.setPicture('picture3.jpg') 
            self.index = 1

gradient_qss = '''QLabel {
                      background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad,
                      x1:1, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0,
                      stop:0 rgb(42, 48, 61),
                      stop:0.05 rgb(42, 48, 61),
                      stop:0.1 rgb(42, 48, 61),
                      stop:0.15 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.999),
                      stop:0.2 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.998),
                      stop:0.25 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.997),
                      stop:0.3 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.996),
                      stop:0.35 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.995),
                      stop:0.4 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.99),
                      stop:0.45 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.985),
                      stop:0.5 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.98),
                      stop:0.55 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.975),
                      stop:0.6 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.97),
                      stop:0.65 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.96),
                      stop:0.7 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.95),
                      stop:0.75 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.93),
                      stop:0.8 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.9),
                      stop:0.85 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.85),
                      stop:0.9 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.8),
                      stop:0.95 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.75),
                      stop:1 rgba(42, 48, 61, 0.7));
                  }'''

label_qss = '''QLabel {
                   color: white;
                   font: bold 16px;
                   background: transparent;
            }'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Молодец! Так держать!